# How can i share my one drive document to other user (in the same domain) through Office 365 REST API?

Tags: api, rest, office365

How can i share my one drive document to other user (in the same domain) through Office 365 REST API.
i checked this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/APi/files-rest-operations but can't file any API which can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid currently we do not have such API to share document to other users directly.

But you can use this one to create a share link and then send it to others.

See this link:
https://dev.onedrive.com/items/sharing_createLink.htm

hope it helps.